# How can I make contingency table with one dependent and several indepentent variables in r, with associtation test result output?

Tags: r, testing, associations

[Contigency table with association test result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jwHp.jpg)
Hi. I want to make a contingency table in R where my independent variable cross with several independent variables, and the last column being the output result of the association test (p value) in each case just like in the picture below. How can I do this?

Comment: First, you would need to have data, then conduct the association analysis. After that, you would be able to table the results. It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample code you've attempted, listing non-base R packages, any errors/warnings received, and sample data, like the output from `dput(head(dataObject)))`. [Check out this resource for great questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).

Comment: I'm pretty new here indeed. And I've found a way to do it. Thanks.